# how do I mount an external hard drive connected via SATA Wire to CentOS 7

Tags: centos, mount, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have CentOS 7 installed as a guest OS inside VirtualBox running on a Windows 8.1 machine.  There is a SATA Wire connecting the machine to an external hard drive that used to contain a dual boot CentOS7/Windows7 machine.

**How can I mount the CentOS 7 partitions of the old external hard drive using the CentOS 7 terminal in the new machine?**

So far, in the CentOS 7 terminal of the new machine, I have typed in:

```
cd /dev/disk/by-id
ls -al
```

The following print screen shows the results (Zoom in to read):

[image]

I also typed in `fdisk -l` and got the following screen shot results:

[image]

**But which results from the above screen shots represent partitions from the external hard drive, and what do I need to type to mount each of those drives?**

For referece, the same external drive viewed from Windows disk manager is the row Disk 1 in the screen shot below.  The CentOS 7 partitions are the right-most few partitions of disk 1:

[image]